# Is it a good practice to extend Laravel models more than one layer?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm reworking a project on Laravel 5.1

What I realize is that the old classes have become much complicated and do not really follow the 'single responsibility' principle anymore.

So I'm planning to do such:

```
<?php

class User extends Model
{

}

class SocialUser extends User
{

}
```

So I have a few questions,

1. Is it possible to achieve that?
2. If yes, then does the *SocialUser* class link back to the same database table which is *Users* and would it conflict with the *User* model itself?
3. Is this all a good design practice at the first place? Or I better make use of traits?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, Yes and Not able to comment without a lot more detail about your specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you’re doing (extending the `User` model) is perfectly fine, and an approach I use myself in projects.

For example, if an application I’m building has shop-like functionality, then I may create a `Customer` model that extends my `User` model, and contains say, order-related relations:

```php
class Customer extends User
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'customer_id');
    }

    public function worth()
    {
        return $this->orders()->sum(function ($order) {
            return $order->total();
        });
    }
}
```

In a recent project, I’ve been working on email campaign functionality and created a `Recipient` class that extends the `User` model to add campaign-related methods:

```php
class Recipient extends User
{
    public function campaigns()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Campaign::class, 'recipient_id');
    }
}
```

Because both of these classes extend the `User` model, I get all of those (and Eloquent) methods:

```php
$customers = Customer::with('orders')->get();
```

So long as you set the table in your base `User` model, any classes that inherit it will use that same table, even though the model may be named differently (i.e. `Customer`, `Recipient`, `Student` etc).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I would go for the Repository pattern. It make's a lot of sense in your situation.

I would do the following:

```
interface UserRepository {

    public function find($id); 
    public function getAll(); 
    public function create(array $attributes);
    public function destroy($id);

    //you get the point

}

class CoreUserRepository implements UserRepository
{

     //implement the interface rules

}

class SocialUserRepository extends CoreUserRepository
{

     //implement the specific logic related to a SocialUser

}
```

### Update

As Mjh described in the comments simply implementing the interface on all `UserTypeRepository` caused repetition - probably not what you want!

By extending your `CoreUser` you avoid repetition & maintain a design that will work for your situation.

Although, in your case it could be argued that you are still following SRP because everything in the `User` model is relating to a user, it's only the type of user which is differing.

### Why go for the Repository Pattern?

- You are ensuring you have a contractual agreement that all `User
  Repositories` need to implement.
- Code is easier to maintain.
- Business and data access logic can be tested separately

### Should you extend your User model?

Here you are in danger of model pollution. While you can do anything with a model - **not everything is a good idea.**

Defining relationships on this approach would be a headache due to the confusion caused.

Comment: So basically, you'd opt for repeating most of the code you actually need and you'd just enforce an interface. Now, that helps development how exactly?

Comment: Readability & maintainability. Building an application is only the beginning you spend more time maintaining & debugging. With that in mind I'd like to make the life of a developer who comes to work on the project in the future easier. If the design implemented becomes a problem/performance hit then you refactor accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so you are solving a problem but not the problem that OP has issue with. What he apparently is after is not repeating the same functions that relate to a user. What you are suggesting is adding an interface and *repeating* all those methods for each class that he needs. How is repeating code related to readability and maintainability? Don't you think you might have missed something?

Comment: He is after a design that separates user types. Which I provided. If you're so hooked up on DRY then you could simply have `MasterUser implements UserRepo` then `SocialUser extends MasterUser` avoiding repetition in `SocialUser`

Comment: So why don't you include that into your answer? The last comment you made makes peace between your concerns and what the OP is after, and it's perfectly valid, avoids repetition and adds structure, maintainability and readability.

Comment: Repositories aren’t the answer for every thing.

Comment: @MartinBean - neither is downvoting with no suggestion how to improve the answer or specifying *why* you don't agree with proposed solution for the particular problem. Doing so is termed *whining*, and no one likes to be labelled as a whiner.

Comment: @Mjh Please don’t stoop to name-calling just because I didn’t laud your answer. The OP asked a question and instead you went on a tangent of implementing an in-vogue alternative.

Comment: @MartinBean - I'm sorry that you have issues with *reading*, but you're downvoting an answer (that is not provided by me) which is perfectly valid and useful, just because you don't agree with it (and you provided exactly 0 reasons *why*). I'm not calling you names, and you provided an answer that's dumbed-down version of this one. Feel free to take whatever you like from it, but if you're opting to help then help, don't build your ego by collecting internet points and harming useful answers.

Comment: @Mjh Apologies. I assumed it was your answer since you were so defensive about it. My answer isn’t a “dumbed down” version of this one (which is essentially saying, “Use repositories”), I provided an answer which actually addresses the OP’s _specific_ questions rather than imposing my opinion of, _you should be using repositories_ on them. Also, for the record, I wasn’t the one who down-voted it.

Comment: @MartinBean - I apologize as well, I jumped to a conclusion. A repository isn't necessarily an answer to everything, but both your answer and this answer use inheritance to avoid repetition - and that's what OP is after, which is perfectly fine, I believe we can agree on that part. I find this answer a bit more detailed on how a repository might help. Personally, I wouldn't go that way if I were in OP's shoes (I'd go with yours) but I do find this answer helpful and accurate for similar use cases. Anyway, sorry once more and have a nice day :)